# Diffs between two versions of a news feed

Tags: algorithm, feed

I'm faced with the following problem: given a news feed (a `rss` one for example) I have to determine what changes occur between different time stamps.
Given the additive nature of such a resource, my best shot was to periodically poll the feed and start looking for new content from the point where the previous version ended.

Is there a more resource (especially space) friendly approach ?

Thank you !

Comment: This seems like a rather simple problem and you seem to have the right idea. Why does your approach use a lot of space? Are you looking to find the changes that occurred since the last check or between any two timestamps? Most of the question points to the prior, but your approach points to the latter.

Comment: I would like to find what was added since the last check. And I think I could avoid keeping all the feed in memory by keeping only the byte size of it and compare it with the new one.

Comment: Assuming there aren't duplicates, you can just keep the last entry and look for that when doing the diff.